# framework 7 get value of range date picker

Tags: javascript, html-framework-7

i trigger range date picker from a button , let say i have

how to set value the selected range date to my

, thank you in advance

```
var date=new Date();
var tgl=date.getDate();
var bln=date.getMonth();
var thn=date.getFullYear();
var calendarRange = myApp.calendar({
    input: '#calendar-range',
    dateFormat: 'M dd yyyy',
    rangePicker: true,
    onClose:function(){

        $$("#selected-date").removeClass("hidden");
        // $$("#selected-date").val(calendarRange.value);
        alert(calendarRange.value);

    },
    disabled:{
        to: new Date(thn, bln, (tgl-1))
    }

});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
onChange: function(p,values,displayValues){
             var start= new Date(values[0]);
             var end = new Date(values[1]); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function onclickCash() {
    var myPicker = $('#calendar-range').val();
    console.log(myPicker);
}
```